# Changing status code changes response body in Express

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a pretty simple helper function to send errors in my response. I use this function all over my codebase:

```
exports.error = function (err, res) {
   res.send({
      success: false,
      errorMsg: err.message,
      errors: err.errors == null ? [] : err.errors
   });
};
```

I decided to add a status code to it:

```
exports.error = function (err, res, status) {
   res.status(status).send({
      success: false,
      errorMsg: err.message,
      errors: err.errors == null ? [] : err.errors
   });
};
```

If the status is 200 I get the body exactly like the object passed to the `send` method. The problem is that if `status` is different from 200 (400 or 500 for example) my response body changes to:

```
{
  config: Object
  data: Object
  headers: function (d)
  status: 500
  statusText: "Internal Server Error"
}
```

And my original response body (the one with `success`, `errorMsg` and `errors` fields) is inside this new response under the `data` attribute. I have no idea why this is happening but as far as I know I don't have any other custom error handlers in my application. I don't want this behavior and instead I want only my original response body.

I am using the `body-parser` package, but I believe that it only affects the requests, not the responses.

Comment: Looks like some other error handler is intercepting it due to the error status code. disable said other handler.

Comment: @KevinB I am absolutely sure I don't have any other error handlers in my own code, but there might be one tucked away in some library I am using. I was hoping someone here in SO would know which one.

Comment: like... express maybe? .....

Comment: I think problem in `res.send(Object)`. Try send data by `res.json(Object)`.

Comment: @AikonMogwai I was using res.json before with the same results.

Comment: Ok. Another place is incorrect exports or order of passed params. It's not Express problem, but included modules. Try `console.log('DEBUG', status, err)` to verify code.

Comment: Let me guess: you're using Angular...

Comment: @robertklep yes I am, I did not even considered that Angular might be changing the response. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response object that you're getting is Angular's response object (see [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)):

> The response object has these properties:
>
> **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>   **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
>   **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
>   **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>   **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

AFAIK, when Angular receives a successful HTTP response (like a 200), it will run any of the [default transformations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations) to convert the response to, say, a JS object (from a JSON response).

However, it won't do that when the HTTP response indicates an error. In that case, you will get the above-mentioned response object back.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem I was having. I thought that express was the one changing the response, not Angular. Thanks! My success handler in angular was returning `response.data`, while my angular error handler was returning `response`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @robertklep I found out that the problem was actually in my Angular code that handled errors. Instead of returning the response body my Angular error handler was returning the error itself.